# Фраза "Расставить все точки над i"

Tags: этимология

Откуда пошло и что означало это выражение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта идиома - калька с французского «mettre les points sur les i et les barres sur les t».

О происхождении фразеологизма рассказывают два источника.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй рассказ добавляет некоторые детали:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Версии позаимствованы [**отсюда**](http://news.flarus.ru/?topic=1788) и [**отсюда**](http://www.topauthor.ru/otkuda_vzyalos_viragenie_rasstavit_vse_tochki_nad_i_1957.html).

---

[...Дословный перевод французской и английской фразы](http://101fakt.ru/rasstavit-tochki-nad-i/)

> звучит как «расставить точки над i и перечеркнуть t». Однако
>   поскольку в русском языке буква т пишется по-другому, но была буква «и
>   десятеричное», по написанию похожая на французскую букву «i», то в
>   русский язык перекочевала только первая часть фразы, которая и звучала
>   как «расставить все точки над «i».

Answer (score 1):

Если позволите, без ссылок, нет сил сейчас искать...

В средние века сложился такой стиль письма, особенно на латыни, слово писалось не отрывая пера или стила от бумаги и только надстрочные знаки вписывались потом. В классической латинице, собственно, такой знак один единственный - точка над i. Многие англичане до сих пор так пишут, только еще букву t верхней чертой перечеркивают вместе с точками над i. И у них бытует поговорка (изначально, кажется, не английская) с аналогичным смыcлом: "перечеркнуть все t".

[тут](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dot_the_i's_and_cross_the_t's)

В переносном смысле это означает: закончить переговоры, согласовать все детали и проч.